Node.js get method take too much time to load
I have tried to use get method in my Node.js CRUD application. It too much time to load in the localhost server.

Please show us your code and the data structure or some samples. What do you mean by "too much time"?

Avoid fetching all data at once; fetch a subset using LIMIT and OFFSET
